# Where do I view impression tracking?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've started using impression tracking in my content blocks, but where do you actually view the report?

Can someone provide me with a pathway, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Impression tracking allows you to track links built with ampscript. This is because when you build links with amspcript, they will not have friendly names unless you use Impression Regions or alias tags.

Once you have declared the impression regions and tagged them with unique identifiers, you can view the information in the Reports or through Data Extracts.

For Reports,

- Navigate to Email Studio > Tracking > Reports
- Under Tracking Reports, you  get the options of "Impression Tracking by Job" or if you are concerned about a Triggered Send, "Impression Tracking for Triggered Sends"

[image]

You get a warning that these reports are not been updated and advised to use analytics builder.

To access the reports via analytics builder,

- Scroll over the marketing cloud icon in the top left to access the drop down and analytics builder
- Select "Reports" then go on to "Email"

[image]

- The Impression Tracking Reports are at the bottom of the page.

[image]

If you use case involves feeding this data directly into 3rd party systems then I would recommend using [data extracts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_extract_types_reference.htm&type=5). Here you can access [SendJobImpression](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_sendjobimpression.htm&type=0), SentImpressions.

**References**:

- [Marketing Cloud Reports](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_email_studio_reports.htm&type=5)
- [Types of Data Extracts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_extract_types_reference.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 5):

The Reports shown above are not automatically enabled.  We had to reach out to our Rep to have those reports available for us to use.