# Reporting on Advanced Content A/B Test blocks

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, analytics, test-setup

I've set up some content items in Content Builder that use an A/B test content block. I'm testing two different images.

How can I report on the performance of emails that use image A vs image B?  Can I do this within Discover Reports?  Or do I need to make use of AMPscript somewhere to pass through impression data for each test?

Comment: Have you looked at impression tracking? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/impressionTracking.htm

Comment: Thank you, what tool can I then to use extract the Impression data that is tracked here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to leverage [Impression Region Tracking](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/impressionTracking.htm):

> Impression tracking lets you define a region within your email to measure the performance of that region. The region you define can contain dynamic content. or you define the region to contain links and images in your static content.

Reporting you can leverage the standard report [Track Impressions by Job Report](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_impression_tracking_by_job_report.htm&type=5) or tracking extract

> The Impression Tracking by Job report for Email Studio in Marketing Cloud Analytics Builder is two reports combined into one. The Job Summary section shows overview tracking information. The Impression Tracking Details section lists the different areas of the report that contained impression tracking and contains data for each area. You can only track emails that use dynamic content or AMPscript .

This is also covered in this post [Where do I view impression tracking?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221773/where-do-i-view-impression-tracking)