# Is there any way to extract email list data along with the rendered subject line where dynamic subject line is used

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-tracking, data-extract, tracking-extract

In all the email, subject line is never hardcoded and dynamic (not individual for each subscriber) but usually our audience list consist of:

- Customer Type 1  - subjectline 1
- Customer Type 2  - subjectline 2
- Customer Type 3  - subjectline 3

Hence, due to the nature of majority of email sends based on customer experience, our emails include subject line - **%%=v(@subjectline)=%%**

and subject line comes from the ampscript in the email body based on customer type.

In email reports and data views where I have checked, subject line is saved as   **%%=v(@subjectline)=%%**

Is there any way to extract email sent in last 90 days along with rendered subject line **(NOT  %%=v(@subjectline)=%%)**

Comment: Have you looked at impression region tracking? If I understand, you have dynamic emails with dynamic content. If you build those with Ampscript, you could then utilize Ampscript Impression Region Tracking because if you know the content you know the subject line. Then I would do a join in automation studio on the report to simply add the subject lines. Documentation on impression region tracking: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221773/where-do-i-view-impression-tracking & https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_impression_region_ampscript.htm&type=5

Comment: It's not possible to do retrospectively, but for the future you could implement Send Logging and add a "subjectline" field to your send logging Data Extension to capture rendered personalised subject lines.

Comment: Yes, we already got impression regions in email that separate dynamic content 1 from dynamic content 2 and so on... @chorlesbarkley7 could you please elaborate on what you mean by join in automation studio on the report to simply add subject line? I am not sure if I am following...some details or example would be helpful..

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the personalized content is not stored in Marketing Cloud unless the Send Log DE is already active. For the future sends you can use SendLog future though, that's the cleanest way to store any dynamic content. Create a "subjectline" field in your Send Log Data Extension that way it's going match and capture each subscribers' subjectline.

Comment: Hi @Ali Eroglu so I haver already looked into this approach, there are a couple of issues in this approach..It is going to be a very custom solution, requires a lot of data stitching, extract sendlog subject line group by job id and subject line then link with data views etc (and if 2 out of 4 impression regions in an email are using same subject lines - senglog won't tell which impression region, it will only give 3 subject lines)

Comment: My goal is to avoid any custom solution because that can have scalability issues and will require move custom work in future for making changes. Anything out of the box would be ideal. Currently, adhoc emails are being sent via automations using email UIs. Is there a different way to configure the email in such a way that rendered subject lines are visible along with the impression region? or reporting can be broken down for a dynamic email?